# LAMP on Digitalocean, Amazon EC2 etc?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, lamp, digital-ocean

Is it possible to build something like serverside database + processing program + webform interface on cloud service such as Digitalocean, Amazon EC2 etc?

I want to make something like http://www.clarifai.com/
So user upload image to web form, program process it, add to db or search in db.

What technologies I should use\install on cloud?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question and I am sure that it will get closed as such.

You seem new to all this, so you should take a tutorial. I think you will find that you have to invest some time before you can actually put something online. It is a bit early to worry about the infrastructure now :)

You mention LAMP, which stands for Linux Apache MySQL PHP (/Perl / Python). So there are your technologies.

You would probably want to use a framework for your project. That offers you a nice environment to start learning. For documentation, I would advise Django. https://www.djangoproject.com/

Check back here once you completed the tutorials.

edit: I think the example you mentioned uses some quite advanced programming, including unsupervised machine learning. You really should try that first and you can build the web application on your own machine. Publishing it is a later worry.